# What authentication should be used for integration Salesforce with Google translation api

Tags: salesforce, google-translate

I am using Google translation api to integrate with Salesforce. I tested my code with API but what should be the exact authentication method to be used for authenticating?

Answer (score 0):

The [**API keys**](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#creating_an_api_key) can be used as authentication method. It can be created directly from the [APIs & Services](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) section of the GCP console, you can use the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/setup) that contains the [step-by-step](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/setup) setup process.

Additionally, I would recommend you to [set some restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#api_key_restrictions) to the in order to define the specific services that can be used with each key (Translation API in this case), as well as determine the web sites, IP addresses, or apps can use an API key; in this way, you can add some additional security to your key avoiding to publicly exposing it which cloud lead to the compromise of your account and the generation of unexpected charges.

Comment: I am using API Keys for authentication on Sandbox but want to know how much secure it is for Production?

Comment: Sandbox itself provides security by isolating environments. But keep in mind API keys are generally not considered secure; they are typically accessible to clients, making it easy for someone to steal an API key. Once the key is stolen, it has no expiration, so it may be used indefinitely, unless the project owner revokes or regenerates the key. To mitigate this you can follow the API key [best practices](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6310037?hl=en), the API usage can be [capped](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage) and

Comment: setting up [notifications](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify#set_up_budget_notifications) that is one way to help gain awareness of charges as they approach predetermined limits.

Additionally, if this will be for internal usage, you can [restrict your API keys](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6310037?hl=en) to be used by only the IP addresses, referrer URLs, and mobile apps that need them.